# Minus 7 days from MYSQL date variable in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a script that counts how many days have past since the start date stored in my database.
The theory is, a user signs up and has 7 days to complete registration, from the admin side of things, this script is used to monitor where a user is upto and how many days have past since they registered.

So in this example we give the user 7 days grace in which to complete. This echos out like '(number of days out of 7 have past'

Then after 7 days this should change to give the number of days overdue. so if a user has 7 days to complete and they take 8 days then this will take into account the first 7 days grace and then have an overdue date of 1 day.

so for instance it should echo out '1 day overdue', rather than what it is currently doing and saying 8 days overdue, i am trying to do this by minusing the first 7 days.

i have been told this will help however i am having trouble getting it  to work with my date variable

```
$pre_date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days'));
```

heres my compelte code, please can someone show me where i am going wrong

```
<?php include 'config.php';
     $data = mysql_query("SELECT *,
                            TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, date, CURDATE()) AS expire_date
                          FROM supplier_session
                          ORDER BY expire_date ASC") 
     or die(mysql_error()); 

     echo "<table class=\"table\" style=\"width:995px;  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
     font-size:11px;\" >

<tr>
    <td style=\"width:100px;\">ID:</td><td>Company Name:</td><td>Company Reg No:</td><td>Application Started:</td><td style=\"width:200px;\">Application Duration:</td><td style=\"width:100px;\">Date:</td><td>Status:</td></tr>";


     while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) { 
       $days = $row['expire_date'];
       $when = $days*0; 
       $str = $row['expire_date'];
       $str2 = substr($str, 0); // "quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."

       $pre_date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days'));

       if ($when <= 31){
         echo "<tr><td style=\"width:100px;\"><p>".$row['id'] . "</p></td>"; 
         echo "<td style=\"width:150px;\"><p>".$row['company_name'] . "</p></td>"; 
         echo "<td style=\"width:150px;\"><p>".$row['company_reg_number'] . "</p></td>";
         echo "<td>"; echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($row['date'])); echo "</td>";

         if ($days >= 8) {
            echo "<td style=\"width:200px;\"><p>{$pre_date} days overdue</td>";      
         }

        elseif ($when <= 7){
             echo "<td style=\"width:200px;\"><p>{$str2} of 7 days past</td>";
          }

        }

        echo "<tr>";
      }

      echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML
    ?>
```

Comment: what is this for: `$when = $days*0; `

Answer (score 0):

I think u have some mistake in ur function

```
$pre_date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days'));
```

For example u can try to use somth like that

```
$datetime = date("Y-m-d", strtotime( date( 'Y-m-d' )." +2 days"));
```

Result of function looks like:

```
2014-05-08
```

Also there more information what u need:

[Click.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

With unixtime looks like that. We take difference between 2 dates in second and divide it on number of seconds in day

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$now_time = time();
$date_before =  time()-(7*24*60*60);// 7 days; 24 hours; 60 mins; 60secs
echo($now_time);
echo('<br>');
echo($date_before);
echo('<br>');
$difference = $now_time - $date_before;
$result = intval($difference/(24*60*60)); //seconds in day
echo($difference);
echo('<br>');
echo($result);
```

also u can get time from date with:

```
$unixtime = strtotime('22-09-2008');
```

Comment: this works, but it give me the date rather than the number of days it is over due, so how do i echo out the number of days which it is overdue please?

Comment: I bad in English. How i understand u have 2 timestamps (unixtime) and one of them is now(). U need differrence between them in days?

Comment: @kickman21 how to get result like: 2 days overdue? instead of 08-05-2014

Comment: I'm change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to pass the date variable to strtotime, so you are always substracting 7 days to the actual date and getting 8 as a result.

Try with a subraction of the actual date minus the expire date in order to get the number of days that have past.